# what is the best data structure for a sorted dict?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a collection of key value pairs where keys are pandas Timestamp and the values are functions. Now I'm wondering what is the most efficient way to store this in python? What is crucial for me is when I update a data structure I would like it to remain sorted, i.e.

```
import pandas as pd

In [98]: t1 = pd.Timestamp('20180101')

In [100]: t2 = pd.Timestamp('20180410')

In [102]: def f(x):
     ...:     pass
     ...: 

In [103]: def g(x):
     ...:     pass
     ...: 

In [105]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [108]: t3 = pd.Timestamp('20180210')

In [109]: def h(x):
     ...:     pass
     ...: 

In [112]: o_dict = OrderedDict({t1: f, t2: g})

In [114]: o_dict.update({t3: h})

In [115]: o_dict
Out[115]: 
OrderedDict([(Timestamp('2018-04-10 00:00:00'), <function __main__.g>),
             (Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), <function __main__.f>),
             (Timestamp('2018-02-10 00:00:00'), <function __main__.h>)])

In [116]: o_dict=OrderedDict(sorted(o_dict.items()))

In [120]: o_dict
Out[120]: 
OrderedDict([(Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), <function __main__.f>),
             (Timestamp('2018-02-10 00:00:00'), <function __main__.h>),
             (Timestamp('2018-04-10 00:00:00'), <function __main__.g>)])
```

Just updating the dictionary leads to a non-sorted dict. I've worked around this by creating a new sorted one but this seems bit clumsy to do every time since I could speed up things drastically knowing it's already a sorted dict before updating. Does there exist a data structure in python? Or how else should I model this?

Comment: check out `sortedcontainers` library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers

Comment: @jpp thx....I cam across it. I would have preferred something form the stdl. If there is no other choice I will maybe add it.